# JAXBvalidation error: 'Invalid index -1' with abstract complexType

Tags: java, validation, wsdl, jaxb

After enabling validation of incoming XML on JAXB web service, I'm getting error message, when I send in request the `Invalid index -1`.

I've checked when this error occures. I'm sending the object, one field of which in an abstract type. When this field is null, validation passes. When this object is sended, the error occurs, no matter what field is set...

The definition of the abstract type:

```xml
<xs:complexType abstract="true" name="Customer">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="address" type="tns:Address"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="nip" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="type" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The definition of concrete type:

```xml
<xs:complexType name="PersonalCustomer">
<xs:complexContent>
<xs:extension base="tns:Customer">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PESEL" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="surname" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

The class definitions (extract) from which the WSDL is generated on CXF startup:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Customer", namespace = "http://dto.sample.pl/")
@XmlSeeAlso({ PersonalCustomer.class,
        CompanyCustomer.class })
public abstract class Customer implements Serializable {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;

    private Address address = new Address();

    private String nip;

    private String type;
}   

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "PersonalCustomer", namespace = "http://dto.sample.pl/")
public class PersonalCustomer extends Customer {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** The PESEL. */
    private String PESEL;

    /** The first name. */
    private String firstName;

    /** The surname. */
    private String surname;
}
```

The error comes from exception thrown when resolving the URI within XML:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid index -1; current element has only 1 attributes
 at com.ctc.wstx.sr.AttributeCollector.throwIndex(AttributeCollector.java:457)[88:woodstox-core-asl:4.0.8]
 at com.ctc.wstx.sr.NsAttributeCollector.getURI(NsAttributeCollector.java:305)[88:woodstox-core-asl:4.0.8]
 at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.getAttributeNamespace(BasicStreamReader.java:585)[88:woodstox-core-asl:4.0.8]
 at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.DepthXMLStreamReader.getAttributeNamespace(DepthXMLStreamReader.java:63)[138:org.apache.cxf.bundle:2.3.3.fuse-01-09]
 at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.getAttributeNamespace(StreamReaderDelegate.java:112)[67:org.apache.servicemix.specs.stax-api-1.0:1.7.0]
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder$AddXSITypeStreamReader.getAttributeNamespace(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:123)[138:org.apache.cxf.bundle:2.3.3.fuse-01-09]
 at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.DepthXMLStreamReader.getAttributeNamespace(DepthXMLStreamReader.java:63)[138:org.apache.cxf.bundle:2.3.3.fuse-01-09]
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector$1.getURI(StAXStreamConnector.java:254)[68:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.1.1_1]
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.fillXMLAttribute(ValidatorHandlerImpl.java:784)[:1.6.0_29]
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.fillXMLAttributes(ValidatorHandlerImpl.java:764)[:1.6.0_29]
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.startElement(ValidatorHandlerImpl.java:546)[:1.6.0_29]
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:96)[68:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.1.1_1]
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleStartElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:242)[68:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.1.1_1]
```

Is something wrong with that definition? What exactly causes the validation error with such enigmatic message?

Comment: can you paste the generated java sources?

Comment: Actually the wsdl is generated from the Java sources, what additional information would posting them provide? I'd like to avoid it, since I'd have to rewrite them anyway because of copyright issues.

Comment: do you mean, that the schema declarations you posted are generated from java source via JAXB?

Comment: then post the jaxb annotated sources